# Generic Interface as a Class Property (or Property in class constructor)

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have an existing Generic interface as below:

```
public interface IWorkflowValidator<T> where T : IPersistent, IStateful, new()
{
   ...
```

The questions is I'd like to have this generic interface either as a Property of another class called WorkflowService or as a property in the WorkflowService class constructor. When I do it like in the Constructor example below the compiler complains - I believe I'm having problems with the T bit (though I could be wrong there).

e.g. WorkflowService Constructor

```
public WorkflowService(ControllerAccess controllerAccess, IValidationDictionary validatonDictionary, IWorkflowValidator<T> workflowValidator) where T: IPersistent, IStateful
    {
```

Comment: What is the question? Please post complete code snippets that compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set generic constraints on the `IWorkflowValidator<T>` that you accept as a constructor argument, you have to make the class itself generic and add the constraints to the class' generic type argument, like this:

```
public interface IWorkflowValidator<T> where T : IPersistent, IStateful, new()
{
}

public class WorkflowService<T> where T : IPersistent, IStateful, new()
{
    private readonly IWorkflowValidator<T> _validator;

    public WorkflowService(IWorkflowValidator<T> validator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public IWorkflowValidator<T> Validator
    {
        get { return _validator; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks khellang that solved my problem - I'm marking youre answer as the 'one'. I'm guessing its not possible to have multiple generic type Class constructor properties then?

Comment: Not sure what "Class constructor properties" are, but if you mean generic constructor arguments, then yes, you can have as many as you want. If they have different generic arguments, you have to add  more generic arguments to the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass generic-interface into you class you had to add generic parameter to your class.

```
public interface IWorkflowValidator<T> where T : IPersistent, IStateful, new() { }

public class WorkflowService<T> where T: IPersistent, IStateful, new()
{
    public WorkflowService(ControllerAccess controllerAccess, IValidationDictionary validatonDictionary, IWorkflowValidator<T> workflowValidator)
    { }
}
```

Or you can create a non-generic version of you interface (base for generic version) and specify type when you create instance of class that implements your generic version of interface.

```
public interface IWorkflowValidator { }

public interface IWorkflowValidator<T> : IWorkflowValidator
    where T : IPersistent, IStateful, new() { }

public class WorkflowService
{
    public WorkflowService(ControllerAccess controllerAccess, IValidationDictionary validatonDictionary, IWorkflowValidator workflowValidator) { }
}
```